# passing button id from one .m to another .m

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uibutton

Need to pass a button id from one .m to another and clear my table view at the same time so i can load new data in.  Nothing seems to be happening, the table still contains what it was populated with on viewDidLoad and the background image does not change. Please help.

There are no warning or errors so im not sure what im doing wrong but the value of senderIdentifier in ClassTwo.h is always 0

Thank you.

in my classOne.m i have the following button action

```
-(IBAction) btnPushViewtabel:(id)sender{    
ClassTwo *classtwo = [[ClassTwo alloc]init];
    classtwo.myTable = nil;
classtwo.senderIdentifier = [sender tag];   
[self.view addSubview:viewtableController.view];
}
```

in ClassTwo.h

```
@interface ClassTwo : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>  {
....
int senderIdentifier; 
} 
@property (nonatomic, readwrite)  int senderIdentifier;
```

in ClassTwo.m

```
if(senderIdentifier == 0){
  // getNewData
  //set background img1
} else {
  // getNewData
  //set background img2
}
```

Comment: [tableView reloadData];?

Comment: Thats what i tried already but i wasnt sure if it was working or not. As im unable to load new data in first place due to not being able to identify which button was pressed. Can you help with my problem with the [sender id] not being passed correctly?>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if(mySenderIdentifier == 0){   //
>   getNewData   //set background img1 }
>   else {   // getNewData   //set
>   background img2 }

what method is this code block in?

**Edit:**

This Line:

> classtwo.mySenderIdentifier = [sender
>   tag];

is called after:

> viewDidLoad

In other words- when you are checking it you havn't actually set it yet.

There are a number of ways to solve this but my personal preference would be to create a custom init method for classTwo like this:

> -(id)initWithSenderIdentifier:(int)identifier{
>
> ```
> if(self=[super init]){
>
>     self.senderIdentifier = identifier;
>     self.myTable = nil;
>
> }     
> return self;
> ```
>
> }

Or elimate the need to store the int (given that's only used to set the background once)

> -(id)initWithSenderIdentifier:(int)identifier{
>
> ```
> if(self=[super init]){
>
>     if(identifier)//set backgroundimg1;
>     else //set backgroundimg2;
>     self.myTable = nil;        
> }     
> return self;
> ```
>
> }

you use it like this:

> ClassTwo *classtwo = [[ClassTwo alloc] 
>   initWithSenderIdentifier:[sender tag]];

If this is helpful, please mark it was answered

Comment: Thank you for looking at this. Its in the viewDidLoad method

Comment: Im still having the same problem, i can see its setting the value but when it runs viewDidLoad it reverts to 0 again.

Comment: Im still having the same problem, i can see its setting the value but when it runs viewDidLoad it reverts to 0 again. Ive added your first solution ato ClassTwo as im using senderIdentifier in other methods.  In ClassOne i have the following 

-(IBAction) btnPushViewtabel:(id)sender{ 
 ClassTwo *classtwo = [[ClassTwo alloc]init];
 [classtwo initWithSenderIdentifier:[sender tag]];
 [self.view addSubview:viewtableController.view];
} 

and ive added this to ClassTwo.h

-(id)initWithSenderIdentifier;

thank you for your time, ive spent all day trying to get it to work.

Comment: you should be using the custom init instead of the default init. see edit above

Comment: hi, thank you so much for your time. i amended my code as you recommended but im still having the same issue with self.senderIdentifier being 0 when called in viewDidLoad and viewDidAppear of ClassTwo. I wont take up any more of your time, im sure its correct but due to my lack of objective-c knowledge im sure im doing something wrong somewhere. To get it working i assigned it to a var in my appDelegate and im calling it from there when i need it. I know is not elegant but its the one i got working. thanks again.